# GetItemByWebDavUrl in anguilla

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm writing an SDL Tridion Anguilla extension and need to pull a config component using a webdav url. The config also has a set of webdav urls and I need to fetch item Objects for these.

Frank - May be I ate a few words in my question.. I'm writing a CMS GUI extension and writing javascript. So is there something like $models.getItem(); which gives me the component or xml of the component?

Comment: What about resolving those webdav urls via a script that is executed when you install your extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most Tridion Content Manager APIs you can read an item by either its TCM URI **or** its WebDAV URL.

So if you're using the Core Service, you can simply do:

```
var item = client.Read(webdavURL, null);
```

Then you can iterate over the fields (if you're using the Core Service this [Fields helper class](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata) will come in handy) and do the same for each value in there.

If you need to have the mapping available to the client, you'll need to create a custom web service to make it available. Although not trivial at first, creating a WCF service is not as daunting as some people make it out to be. Especially not when you start with [this example of a minimal WCF service for Tridion](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/AddingMinimalWcfService).

Comment: Many Thanks Frank, the minimal service is implemented and works like a charm. Though I believe such a basic function should be available out of the box.

Comment: Most SDL Tridion products and add-ons do their mappings on the server, to avoid having to do roundtrips for them. So if you have a WebDAV URL somewhere, why not convert it to a TCM URI on the server in a data extender? It may be a bit more work initially, but your users on higher latency connection will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no functionality on the client to resolve items by WebDAVUrl. The only functionality we have is:

```
var item = $models.getItem(tcmUri);
item.getWebDavUrl();   // will return you WebDAVUrl, if it was loaded before
item.loadWebDavUrl();  // will make async call to load WebDAVUrl. "loadwebdavurl" or "loadwebdavurlfailed" will be fired on the item afterwards
```